# Widgets keep repeating/duplicating in KV file

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have a UI designed in KV language, as follows:

```
<MainLayout>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation:"horizontal"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        Button:
            size_hint:(1,.9)
            text:"1"
        Button:
            size_hint:(1,.1)
            text:"2"
```

Here is the accompanying `py` file:

```
from kivy import Config
from kivy.app import App, Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

with open('gui.kv', 'r') as kv:
    Builder.load_string(kv.read())


class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class GuiApp(App):
    Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1600')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1000')

    def build(self):
        self.title = "TestGUI"
        return MainLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GuiApp().run()
```

I want an asymmetrical layout, where the main window has two columns, and the left column has two widgets (top and bottom halves) and the right column is similar.
Each of the widgets in each column needs to be asymmetric in height.

For whatever reason, the given design above keeps "repeating" my left and right halves, there is no "blank" space.
I wanted two `BoxLayout`, one for each column. My `<MainLayout>` is also a `BoxLayout`. I have tried making that a `GridLayout` with `cols:2` as well, but I get similar results.

**This is my output:**
[image: Current output]

So, tl;dr, the left column is exactly correct, but it repeats to the right half as well. How can I change that?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added the accompanying `py` file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem - Two Root Widgets

You are getting the column repeated because there are two root widgets. One from `Builder.load_string(kv.read())` and the other one from `class GuiApp()` i.e. by **Builder** and by **name convention** respectively.

## Solution

Remove the following:

```
with open('gui.kv', 'r') as kv:
    Builder.load_string(kv.read())
```

Since `<MainLayout>` is a BoxLayout, therefore you do not need another BoxLayout. Please refer to the example for details.

## Note

[How to load KV](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv)

> There are two ways to load Kv code into your application:
>
> **By name convention:**
>
> Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in
>   lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:
>
> ```
> MyApp -> my.kv
> ```
>
> If this file defines a Root Widget it will be attached to the App’s
>   root attribute and used as the base of the application widget tree.
>
> **By Builder** You can tell Kivy to directly load a string or a file. If this string or file defines a root widget, it will be returned by
>   the method:
>
> ```
> Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> Builder.load_string(kv_string)
> ```

## Example

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MainLayout>:
    orientation:"horizontal"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        Button:
            size_hint:(1,.9)
            text:"1"
        Button:
            size_hint:(1,.1)
            text:"2"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        Button:
            size_hint:(1,.9)
            text:"3"
        Button:
            size_hint:(1,.1)
            text:"4"
```

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: Thanks a lot @ikolim, but I am confused about your solution. Your output shows similar results to mine, you have "1" and "2" repeating on the left and right column.
I want to modify the widgets, etc. in each column independently, instead of having them repeat.

Comment: Where do you plan to update the widgets i.e. in kv file or Python code? Please refer to updated post without dynamic class.

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/aZQegGe) is what I get with your updated code, I had tried this myself as well.
I want static widgets, defined in the `kv` file, which I will use to call functions in my `py` file. The functionality is not the issue at the moment, the UI design is.

Comment: The repeated columns was due to two root widgets in your App. Remove `with open('gui.kv', 'r') as kv:
    Builder.load_string(kv.read())`

Comment: Please refer to my updated post for the explanation.